# Why is the Particle effect like this? .....(see pic)(I followed every step as shown by BlenderGuru Tutorial (Donut).)

Tags: modeling, particles

I tried multiple times but I am not getting what is wrong with the particle effect even though I followed the steps as shown by Blender Guru.
Here I am getting an effect like this:[image]
Can you guys tell me why is this happening?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yo have moved the object away from its origin point in edit mode. Select your particle object (the one you used to make the particles) select the whole thing in edit mode and move it around. You'll see how it changes the position of the particles relative to the donut.